# TYPO3 CKEditor can't select file images

Tags: php, ckeditor, typo3

I'm using CKEditor for my text & images contents, I have the icon for insert images, but when I click on it, I don't have the menu to choose my image instead of it, I have the property image menu to select urls, widht and height.

Someone can help me to resolve this configuration issue ? thanks you

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this extension for ckeditor images:

https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image

Install via extensions or the way the readme tells you to.

Put this line in for instance typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'EXT:my_ext/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';
```

Follow the rest of the installation process...

Works great in TYPO3 v9.5.x

Comment: I solved my issue, "    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor_image/Configuration/RTE/Plugin.yaml" }" was disabled, thanks you